# Probability prisoners starving

Tags: probability

In a prison there are $n$ cells and in $k$ ($k<n$) of them the prisoner will get food and water. The prisoners ($n$) are put in a row and each one of them gets to draw from a box a ball, the balls are of two kinds white and black, if the ball is white they are put in the nice cell, if the ball is black they get into the starvation cell.  What is the probability that the $j$-th prisoner will draw a white ball?

I started with the easy cases aka for $j=2$. In this situation the probability depends on what the first prisoner in the row drawed.

If A is the event that the prisoner in case j gets the white ball, and F is the even that the first prisoner got a white ball then $$P(A) =P(A/F) P(F) +P(A/!F) P(!F)=\frac{k-1}{n-1}\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k}{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n}=\frac{(k-1)k +k(n-k) } {n(n-1)} =\frac{k} {n} $$ Here !F denotes the event that F did not get a white ball (aka got a black one).

Even for j=3 I am having trouble to set things up for calculation. Consider the case where the second prisoner gets a white ball S. 
$$P(A)= P(A/F) P(F) +P(A/!F) P(!F)+P(A/S) P(S) +P(A/!S) P(!S) $$I wrote that, but I feel something is missing cause I must depend on what did the first prisoner choose in order to get the probability for the second one. 
Some help?

Comment: Does the whole question show up? Am from phone and I only see:In a prison there are n cells and in k (k. But in the edit section everything is there.

Comment: The first line is broken.

Comment: HINT The probability of drawing a white ball is exactly the same for each prisoner, whether they are first, second, last, or $j$-th in the original line-up. ...  indeed, I note that you made a mistake for $j=2$: that should work out to $\frac{k}{n}$

Comment: But that would mean $P(A/S) P(S) +P(A/!S) P(!S)=0$.. Thanks, I typed in a hurry, on my notebook I had $\frac{k} {n} $

Comment: @Porogami No, they each have a $\frac{k}{n}$ chance. Indeed, it worked out like that for $j=2$ ... for $j=3$ it should work out as well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should of course all have a chance of exactly $\frac{k}{n}$ to draw a white ball ... so for any $j$, it should work out to that.

Now, you have that for $j=2$.

Let's now do $j=3$:

We get $$P(A)=$$

$$P(A|F,S)\cdot P(F,S)+P(A|F',S)\cdot P(F',S)+P(A|F,S')\cdot P(F,S')+P(A|F',S')\cdot P(F',S')$$

$$=\frac{k-2}{n-2}\cdot \frac{k-1}{n-1} \cdot \frac{k}{n} + \frac{k-1}{n-2}\cdot \frac{k}{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-k}{n} + \frac{k-1}{n-2}\cdot \frac{n-k}{n-1} \cdot \frac{k}{n} +\frac{k}{n-2}\cdot \frac{n-1-k}{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-k}{n}$$

work that out ... and you should get $\frac{k}{n}$

Comment: Thanks, give me some time to understand why I thought differently.

Comment: I got it! Can you tell me how did you figure out the answer even for the general case in such a short time? Is there any intuition behind without direct calculation (I assume that's how you got it).

Comment: @Porogami lining up all prisoners and then having them draw a ball one by one does not give you can different outcome then randomly distributing all balls among the prisoners. So, each prisoner has the same chance of getting a white ball.